# mySQL Sum in the sum column

Tags: mysql

```
      SELECT tbl_trans.trans_username,
    Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_type <> 'REWARD' AND tbl_trans.trans_winlose <> 'QB' then
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) BETHOST,
    Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_winlose = 'QB'  then
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) QB, 
     Sum(Case When tbl_trans.trans_type = 'REWARD'  then
         trans_winloseamount Else 0 End) reward ,
         Sum(sum(BETHOST)+sum(QB)+sum(reward)) totalsum
 FROM tbl_trans 
 GROUP BY trans_username
```

i need to totalsum of BETHOST,QB and reward
how to sum of this `Sum(sum(BETHOST)+sum(QB)+sum(reward)) totalsum`

Comment: In the same result as the above query or one summarized row?

Comment: @GurV in the same result, same query

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

pls try this

```
sum(SELECT(BETHOST))+sum(SELECT(QB))+sum(SELECT(reward)) AS totalsum
```